# Snyk.io how do I target it to run on a specific branch and not the default branch?

Tags: security

I am using snyk.io to run security scan on GitHub Repos.
When I run the report it only picks up the default branch from the repo and run the test against it.
I want to know how I can target this test against a specific branch and create a report from that run.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @SujanAdiga yes this feature was recently introduced on Snyk for our account as beta. Not sure if this available as GA yet. If you need this too, we contacted our Snyk Account Manager and she helped us getting this enabled.

Comment: Oh. Okay. Thanks @Hbargujar.
I also found a way to get this data. If we have Snyk added as a CI hook in github, it will run on every commit for any pull request, then, a URL like `https://app.snyk.io/org/<organisation_name>/test/github/<project_id_in_snyk>/<commit_sha_for_the_latest_commit_of_pr>` will give vulnerable packages as of the mentioned commit

Comment: @SujanAdiga yes that is another way, In our case we wanted before and after report on two different branches. Also, be aware of the fact the SNYK CLI results are more accurate than the SNYK Web Scan via hooks.

Comment: Also, be aware of the fact the SNYK CLI results are more accurate than the SNYK Web Scan via hooks - I agree.

Answer (score 1):

*--target-reference* is your friend in this case. In short with it's help you can specify a different branch or simply separate projects into different groupings. More on this can be explained from the [documentation](https://docs.snyk.io/snyk-cli/test-for-vulnerabilities/grouping-projects-by-branch-or-version)